# Identifying the Inbox folder through IMAP

Tags: java, imap

I have connected to an email Store via IMAP (outlook.office365.com).  I can work out which folders to use for deleted, spam, outbox and so on, using the LIST command which passes back flags that I can use.

The question is, "how do I know what to use for the InBox".  I could just hard-code the name, but that seems likely to fail rapidly.  I am sure I am missing something, because if the other folders are tagged, then "inbox" would be a strange omission.

Looking forward to your help.  Thanks.

PS - I am doing this with the Java Mail API if that makes a difference to the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By protocol specification, the main folder is a special folder always named INBOX.

See [IMAP RFC 3501 §5.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#section-5.1):

> The case-insensitive mailbox name INBOX is a special name reserved to
> mean "the primary mailbox for this user on this server".  The
> interpretation of all other names is implementation-dependent.